# Replace string in Array in array with truncate string

Tags: php, codeigniter, tumblr, truncate

I'm using CodeIgniter for my website.  I'm also using the tumblr API on my site to show posted news.

Because showing the entire text is a bit too much, I want to truncate the body copy to 150 characters, I do this by using the `character_limiter` function of CI.

The code is as followed in my 'home' controller:

```
public function index() {       
    //Title for home page   
    $data['title'] = "Home - Welcome";

    // Obtain an array of posts from the specified blog
    // See the config file for a list of settings available
    $tumblr_posts = $this->tumblr->read_posts();

    foreach($tumblr_posts as $tumblr_post) {
        $tumblr_post['body'] = character_limiter($tumblr_post['body'], 150);
    }

    // Output the posts 
    $data['tumblr_posts'] = $tumblr_posts;      

    // Load the template from the views directory
    $this->layout->view('home', $data);
}
```

The problem is, that `$tumblr_post['body']` isn't shortened when I echo it on my view page.  Doing it like above works in Asp.net (C#) but it doesn't seem to work in php, anyone know why and how to solve it or is there an other way?

Comment: Did you include Text helper..?

Comment: I would encourage you to do this in the View as opposed to the Controller.

Comment: Please, post the code of the function character_limiter()?

Comment: @eljunior: character_limiter is Codeigniters Text helper function

Comment: ah! cool! didn't know that one...

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: I want to keep the view as clean as possible. Up until recently I used a simplified version of a library/framework spoon, plonk, which relies on templates a lot and because I used that all the time I've grown accustomed to the idea of keeping as much code as possible away from the view/template/front end and personally I have to agree with that thought although the whole template style is a bit redundant.

eljunior: as Sudhir mentioned it is part of the CI framework and it basically truncates the string but keeps the words intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `foreach` loop.  You need to add a `&` before `$tumblr_post` to pass it by reference.  This makes sure you are actually editing the values in the array.  Without the `&`, you're just editing a local variable and not the array.

Try it like this (notice the `&`):

```
foreach($tumblr_posts as &$tumblr_post) {
    $tumblr_post['body'] = character_limiter($tumblr_post['body'], 150);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it :) Thanks.

is the & something like this in (OO) C#?

Comment: @reaper_unique: The `&` tells PHP to pass the variable by reference.  I don't know C#, so I don't know how it handles them.